# Is it possible to block HTML rendering by JavaScript on purpose?

Tags: javascript

I used to use `alert` to halt the rendering. However, recently I noticed that the `alert` can be automatically killed in some cases.

So I am thinking, is there any way to stop the HTML rendering?

A widely used way is to use a breakpoint but there is any way that I could put something in the source code to do so? or to invoke a pause in the console?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to accomplish here?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible in a clean way. The only Javascript blocking functions are `alert`, `confirm` and `prompt`. You can force a breakpoint with the `debugger` keyword, but it will only work if the DevTools are opened.

Answer (score 0):

This would kind of work:

```js
let start = Date.now()
let defertime = 10*1000 // 10 second deferring

while (Date.now() - start < defertime) {
  // do nothing but block JS and page rendering
}

console.log('continuing')
```

Comment: Theoretically works, but it's a busy wait which will eat the entire UI thread and prevent user interaction, so I strongly advise against using it!

Answer (score -3):

You could “sleep” the page for a set amount of time by doing this: [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/what-is-the-javascript-version-of-sleep)